# Dojo Enhanced Grid won't work properly in IE 9

Tags: javascript, dojo, grid

I have an enhanced grid which is connected to an Object Store (which contains a Memory Store). The structure is quite simple, i.e. it just shows rows with no "no scroll" or something like this. 
In Opera, Chrome and FF everything works just fine, but in IE the positioning of the content from the grid is totally wrong. Unfortunatly, I can't post pictures, but I've asked this question also on the dojo mailing list, where I have uploaded the pictures. Here is the link: 
http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Problem-with-the-positioning-of-the-grid-in-ie-9-td3989165.html

I have searched a lot, and tried quite a few things, but nothing has changed anything so far... . Any help would really be appreciated.

Here is the code how I set up the grid:

```
var grid = new EnhancedGrid({
                        id: "grid",
                        store: dataStore,
                        query: filter,
                        autoWidth: true,
                        autoHeight: true,
                        keepRows: '5',
                        rowCount: '60',
                        plugins: {
                            nestedSorting: true,
                            cookie: {expires : 10},
                            exporter: true,
                            indirectSelection: { headerSelector:true, width:'30px', styles:'text-align: center;'} ,
                            menus: { rowMenu:"row_menu" }
                        },
                        structure: grid_structure
                    }, "grid");
grid.startup();
```

Thx in advance, 
Gernot

Comment: I've some new information.
It seems, that the IE isn't recognizing (or working prober with) the css class dojoxGridContent. I think so, becaue, this is the class in which the content is embedded. And, if I change anything in the class Opera displays as i thought it would be, but IE does nothing with it. (I've included a margin-top: 20px)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey you can't directly catch the error. Do some trail and error development for IE. I have also faced so many issues with IE and Dojo DataGrid.

Remove all cookie, selection and extra features from your grid and keep it very simple. Try to make the basic one working on IE.

Then one by one add the features and verify that they are working fine, you will get the culprit in the process.

In the process, remember to clear browser cache frequently.

Its tedious job you will have a lot of satisfaction after resolving the issue.

All the best.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I solved it somehow. I had to import also the "Grid.css" file. I don't know why, but in the IE the import url("Grid.css") tag from the claroGrid.css file wasn't executed.